# Android - Supporting Multiple Screens and layout margins

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have developed an app and tested it in an android phone which has a resolution of 480*640, it was just fine. Now I installed that app on samsung galaxy tab 3, now everything is looking too small, how do I make the layout to fit in the device of any resolution?

In the same application, in one of the xml file, I am hard-coding the layout margin as `android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"`, how do I avoid hard-coding?

Thank you for any help..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Comment: Using `dp` instead of 'px' in your layout

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Multi-Screen Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584025/android-multi-screen-application)

Comment: I am using dp only, but still..

Comment: @Marius, yes, as you told I searched in google and stack overflow as well, and documentation also, and I tried all those but not working for me, that's the reason I posted here..

Comment: you can use [dimen.xml](https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicSyncAdapter/res/values/dimen.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to check in order to solve the problem:

- Open each one of your xml files with the layouts and make sure that your layout has as less as possible numbers in it. Do not use `px` (pixels in design) read and understand how `dp` and `sp` work and use them wisely and carefully! Prefer `wrap_content` and `match_parent`. Read the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseWrapMatchPar)
- In order to avoid the use of FIXED dimensions see how [`RelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseRelativeLayout) works.
- If you have many image resources think about replacing them with [Nine-patch images](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUse9Patch) (in sort, images that can scale themselves in order to fill an area)
- For image resources that cannon be changed with nine-patch or where you need to improve the way something looks use different images for different screen densities. More about drawable folders [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html#TaskProvideAltBmp). And [here](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html) are some tools to help you generate resources.

These are enough to start with, but if you want to write a really good app then read the whole documentation for [**Designing for Multiple Screens**](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)

Comment: I have xml files in layout folder and layout-xlarge folder(did it by referring to documentation), and I have numbers in xml which are necessary and all those are in dp, I have not used px anywhere in the xml.. but still it is not showing the exact dimensions:(

Comment: The base layout is placed in `layout` folder all other folders usually used for very specific cases such as to achieve multi-screen layouts. I try not use any number at all in my layouts, and that makes the screens fit better everywhere!

Comment: Ya but the requirement is like that, they are asking to put the margin of 5dp for small phones and 15dp for large, how could I do this?

Comment: Sorry to say that but for the mentioned dimensions it seems that they are asking you to write a Non-Android app. See here: https://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html